# Property currently unsupported: 'concurrencyMode'

Tags: rest-api, servicecloud, workbench, concurrency

I was playing with [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php) and tried to create job in "Rest Explorer".
The Url I was using:

```
/services/data/v41.0/jobs/ingest/
```

The Request Headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json
```

Request Body:

```
{
  "object":"Contact",
  "contentType":"CSV",
  "operation": "insert",
  "concurrencyMode": "Serial"
}
```

I was executing a POST request. However I received this error "Property currently unsupported: 'concurrencyMode'"

Anyone has any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: You may need to upgrade to API version 42.0, does that make any difference? '/services/data/v42.0/jobs/ingest/'

Comment: Not really. The highest version is 41.0 and I tried with 42.0 actually, but it doesn't work.

Comment: hi @Vera I am also facing the similar issue, by any chance do you know how to set concurrency mode to serial via rest api?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this finally. Looks like Salesforce was expecting the xml attributes to be passed in same order. Order change was causing the problem for me and was returning 400 Bad Request Error.

```
<jobInfo xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
                <operation>insert</operation>
                <object>SomeObjectName</object>
                <concurrencyMode>Serial</concurrencyMode>
                <contentType>CSV</contentType>
</jobInfo>
```

As shown above Serial has to be after object attribute and before contentType.

Comment: This is Bulk API 1.0, the question is about Bulk API 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error, maybe it is not exposed through REST API or WorkBench.

But as per this trailhead [Use Bulk API](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/api_basics/units/api_basics_bulk) to create a job in WorkBench you don't have to pass `concurrencyMode` attribute. By [default](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/create_job.htm), it is set to Parallel.

[image]

Click **Execute** and check out the response.

[image]

Comment: So cannot set it to Serial with REST API?